# VBA: How to hide the floating toolbar shown on right clicking on a shape or document area in Microsoft Visio?

Tags: vba, toolbar, visio

I am trying to hide the floating toolbar that shows up shown when right-clicking on a shape or document area in Visio Plan 2. Tried to with toolbar objects but it still shows up.

Below is the code attempted,

```
Sub HideFloatingToolbar()
    Dim uiObj As Visio.UIObject
    Dim toolbarObj As Visio.Toolbar
    Dim toolbarItemsObj As Visio.toolbarItems
    Dim toolbarItemObj As Visio.ToolbarItem
    Dim i As Integer
    'Retrieve the UIObject object for the copy of the built-in toolbars
    Set uiObj = Visio.Application.BuiltInToolbars
    'Set toolbarObj to the Drawing menu set.
    Set toolbarObj = uiObj.ToolbarSets.ItemAtID(Visio.visUIObjSetDrawing)
    'Retrieve the toolbar items collection.
    Set toolbarItemsObj = toolbarObj.toolbarItems
    'Retrieve the toolbar item by
    'iterating through the toolbar items collection and
    'locating the item
    For i = 0 To toolbarItemsObj.Count - 1
        Set toolbarItemObj = toolbarItemsObj.Item(i)
        'Trying to test with the first item but not sure what
        'to compare against to hide it
        If toolbarItemObj.toolbarItems.Item(1).Caption = "????" Then
            'hide it
            toolbarItemObj.Visible = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    'Tell Visio to use the new custom toolbars while the
    'document is active.
    ThisDocument.SetCustomToolbars uiObj
End Sub
```

Below is the screenshot of the toolbar I am referring to.

[image: Floating toolbar]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to hide this thing (it's called "mini toolbar" in the microsoft docs as of my knowledge). All you can do is to disable some commands on it (by standard disabling command by id i.e.

```
<customUI ...>
  <commands>
    <command idMso="PictureInsertFromFile" enabled="false"/>
    <command idMso="ChartInsert" enabled="false"/>
  </commands>
</customUI>
```

Comment: oh, bad to know. I guessed if it can appear, there has to be some identifier to this "mini toolbar" with properties. Thank you for the reply Nikolay!